# Proof that the normed space $(l^{\infty},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I have to prove that $(l^{\infty},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is Banach space and I have some difficulties. This is what I've done.

$l^\infty=\{x=\langle x_k\rangle, k\in N|\exists M>0 \ such\ that\forall k\in N |x_k|\leq M\}$
$\|x\|_\infty=\sup\{|x_k|:k\in N\}$

Let $\langle x^n:n\in N\rangle$ be a Cauchy sequence in $l^\infty$.
$x^1=\langle x^1_1,x^1_2,...,x^1_k,...\rangle$
$x^2=\langle x^2_1,x^2_2,...,x^2_k,...\rangle$
.
.
.
$x^n=\langle x^n_1,x^n_2,...,x^n_k,...\rangle$

Since it is Cauchy sequence, I know that it holds
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in N)(\forall m,n\geq n_0)\|x^n-x^m\|_\infty<\epsilon$
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in N)(\forall m,n\geq n_0)\sup\{|x^n_k-x^m_k|:k\in N\}<\epsilon$
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in N)(\forall m,n\geq n_0)(\forall k\in N)|x^n_k-x^m_k|<\epsilon$

Now I can choose an arbitrary $k_*\in N$ such that
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in N)(\forall m,n\geq n_0)|x^n_{k_*}-x^m_{k_*}|<\epsilon$

This means that $\langle x^n_{k_*}:n\in N\rangle$ is Cauchy sequence in $(R,|\cdot|)$ which is complete, so $\langle x^n_{k_*}:n\in N\rangle$ is convergent. That means that there is $x_{k_*}\in R$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^n_{k_*}=x_{k_*}$.

Since $k_*$ was arbitrary, we can do this for all $k\in N$ so we get that there exists a sequence $x=\langle x_k\rangle$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^n_k=x_k$,$\forall k\in N$.

This sequence, $x=\langle x_k\rangle$ is a candidate for a limit of a sequence $\langle x^n\rangle$.

I have to show now that $x\in l^\infty$.
I know that $l^\infty$ is vector space. Also I know that for some $n_0\in N$ $x^{n_0}\in l^\infty$.
If I write $x$ as $x=(x-x^{n_0})+x^{n_0}$ it's enough to show that $x-x^{n_0}\in l^\infty$

I know from what I wrote above that
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in N)(\forall m,n\geq n_0)(\forall k\in N)|x^n_k-x^m_k|<\epsilon$
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in N)(\forall n\geq n_0)(\forall k\in N)(\forall m\geq n_0)|x^n_k-x^m_k|<\epsilon$
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in N)(\forall n\geq n_0)(\forall k\in N)\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}|x^n_k-x^m_k|\leq\epsilon$
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in N)(\forall n\geq n_0)(\forall k\in N)|x^n_k-\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}x^m_k|\leq\epsilon$
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in N)(\forall n\geq n_0)(\forall k\in N)|x^n_k-x_k|\leq\epsilon$
For $\epsilon=1$ I can find $n_0$ such that $(\forall k\in N) |x^{n_0}_k-x_k|\leq 1$

Since this hold for all $k\in N$, than it holds that $\sup\{|x^{n_0}_k-x_k|:k\in N\}\leq 1$
i.e. $\|x^{n_0}_k-x_k\|_\infty=\|x_k-x^{n_0}_k\|_{\infty}<1=\epsilon$ i.e. $(x_k-x^{n_0}_k)\in l^{\infty}$

Is this correct? If it is, then I have to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x^n=x$ and that's all.
If it is not, please help me.

Comment: Wow, too many quantifiers, this is pretty much unreadable. I suspect you have all it needs for the proof but I can't read a thing.

Comment: It's correct so far. And your last  step shows basically that if $\lVert x^n - x^m\rVert_\infty \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $n,\,m \geqslant N$, then $\lVert x^n - x\rVert_\infty \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $n \geqslant N$.

Comment: Well, they are repeating mostly... you can skip quantifiers and read just the part which is $<\epsilon$ :D

Comment: @DanielFischer So this is how I should show it? I thought it might have some bigger differences from proof that metric space is complete. I know that norm induces metric, but still I thought it would be much more different.

Comment: @gov : If you wrote things that I should skip then they shouldn't be written. I'm not just saying this for me, you should be able to read what you wrote yourself, too.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I can read it easily. Daniel Fischer could do it too.

Comment: Well, you should try to make it shorter and with that more readable. But basically, that's it, you show that each coordinate is a Cauchy sequence, hence convergent, the boundedness of Cauchy sequences shows that the sequence of limits is bounded, then you show that the sequence of limits is the limit.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Daniel, so far is correct, but you need to finish your proof. Your last argument shows that $x - x^n \in l^{\infty}$, hence $x = (x-x^n) + x^n \in l^{\infty}$ too. The last computations you did should show that $x^n \to x$.

Comment: @gov : Don't get me wrong, what you wrote is not invisible, I can read it! I'm just saying that the presentation is very heavy. You should learn to lighten it up, it would help you understand yourself better.

Comment: Well, our professors require to write every line when we have written exam. If we don't write everything they won't know if we understand how did we get it and we will get less points. I've learned to write every line. Sorry for making this hard to read. Thank you very much, to both of you, Patric and Daniel. :)

Comment: @gov That is OK, but use more words instead! It is easier to read that way.

Comment: @gov : I'm sorry that you professor either taught you to do that or led you to think that you had to. I'm confident in saying that this is not an optimal way to write mathematics, i.e. to write plenty of lines full of repeated symbols. I am also confident that you understand mathematics, since what you wrote up there is non-trivial and needs understanding of mathematics to be done ; so I think that if you find a way to put less symbols and allow someone to read what you wrote twice as fast, you would have improved by a huge factor. =D That is what I would suggest to improve your answer above.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Ok, I will do my best to avoid writing like I wrote above and use more words instead. It is true that I sometimes get lost in all these symbols when I'm reading what we have written at classes but somehow I (and my classmates) started to write it automatically. I agree that it would be easier to read if it is explained by words and I will practice from now to write that way. Thanks a lot for your effort and advice. :)

Comment: One more question - when I am showing that $x$ is in some space which I want to show that is Banach, do I always have to use a fact that that space is vector space, to write $x$ as $x=x-x^{n_0}+x^{n_0}$ and to show that $x-x^{n_0}$ is in that space because I already know that $x^{n_0}$ is in that space (as I did above)? For example, when I was showing that $(c,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is Banach, I showed that $x$ in Cauchy sequence in $(R,|\cdot|$ which means that it is convergent so it is in $c$.